# Laravel Authentication system- Tables do not match

Tags: php, laravel

I get an error that I am trying to understand: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = hi@hi.hi limit 1) when trying to login

My 'users' table:
id  email   password    name    admin   created_at  updated_at
1   go@go.go    $2y$10$1R/21A3C32nwkjtEgDFcyuMc2D4AtgeFnTh1ygLEcQl...   go  1   2014-11-01 21:04:33     2014-11-01 21:04:33
2   hi@hi.hi    $2y$10$Akb9BoLWrOcQT0KFee7vvujtrzkbeRQnUDcuCXepeAd...   hi  0   2014-11-02 16:15:47     2014-11-02 16:15:47

My form in views (displays correctly)

```
@extends('login_c')

@section('loginform')
<?= '<span style="color:red">' .
Session::get('login_error') . '</span>' ?>
{{ Form::open() }}
{{ Form::label('email', 'Email address: ') }}
{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email')) }}
<br>
{{ Form::label('password', 'Password: ') }}
{{ Form::password('password') }}
<br>
{{ Form::submit('Login!') }}
{{ Form::close() }}


@stop
```

The problem is that I specified my password before in the registration and I do not understand why I either get "Could not login" or the SQL injection error.

```
oute::get('registration', function()
{
return View::make('registration');
});

Route::post('registration', array('before' => 'csrf',
function()
{
    $rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|same:password_confirm',
    'name' => 'required'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('registration')->withErrors
        ($validation)->withInput();
    }
    $user = new User;
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->admin = Input::get('admin') ? 1 : 0;
    if ($user->save())
    {
        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        return Redirect::to('profile');
    }
    return Redirect::to('registration')->withInput();
}));

Route::get('profile', function()
{
if (Auth::check())
{
return 'Welcome! You have been authorized!';
}
else
{
return 'Please <a href="login">Login</a>';
}
});

Route::get('login', function()
{
return View::make('login');
});

Route::post('login', function()
{
$user = array(
'name' => Input::get('email'),
'password' => Input::get('password')
);
if (Auth::attempt($user))
{
return Redirect::to('profile');
}
return Redirect::to('login')->with('login_error',
'Could not log in.');
});

Route::get('secured', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
return 'This is a secured page!';
}));
```

My register form: (Sorry, I am not posting my full view, as it is not relevant, I am sure that the error is in the form and/or usermodel.

```
{{ Form::open() }}
{{ Form::label('email', 'Email address: ') }}
{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email')) }}
<br>
{{ Form::label('password', 'Password: ') }}
{{ Form::password('password') }}
<br>
{{ Form::label('password_confirm',
'Retype Password: ') }}
{{ Form::password('password_confirm') }}
<br>
{{ Form::label('name', 'Name: ') }}
{{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name')) }}
<br>
{{ Form::label('admin', 'Admin?: ') }}
{{ Form::checkbox('admin','true',
Input::old('admin')) }}
<br>
{{ Form::submit('Register!') }}
{{ Form::close() }}


@stop
```

How should I change my user model? Why does it save the wrong password?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```php
$user = array(
'name' => Input::get('email'),
'password' => Input::get('password')
);
```

to

```php
$user = array(
'email' => Input::get('email'), // You're using email to log in users, not name in your form
'password' => Input::get('password')
);
```

Comment: Thank you. One question: WHy is it showing me the wrong password if I open the database? Is this a security feature?

Comment: @StephanieNess You're welcome. What do you mean by *...it showing me the wrong password if I open the database...*?